# Add a column to populate rank for every group

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift, rank

I've history data with account details, where the account activity status is either 'Active' or 'Cancelled'.When the account is re-opened the account status becomes 'Active' and later can become 'cancelled' as below data. Now I would like to differentiate the data every-time the account is re-opened(with account_sub_number).

I've used the below query:

```
select status,status_code,account_number,date, 
row_number() over (partition by account_number,status_code order by 
date  ) as Account_Sub_Number
 from schema.account where account_number= 1234
 order by date
```

Source_data:

```
Account Number  Status  Status Code Date
1234    Active  A   2017-12-04
1234    Active  A   2017-12-05
1234    Active  A   2017-12-06
1235    Active  A   2017-12-07
1234    Active  A   2018-03-02
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-03-03
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-03-04
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-05-10
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-05-11
1234    Active  A   2018-05-24
1234    Active  A   2018-05-25
1234    Active  A   2018-05-26
1234    Active  A   2018-05-27
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-05-28
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-06-15
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-06-16
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-06-17
```

Required output:

```
    Account Number  Status  Status Code Date    Account Sub Number
1234    Active  A   2017-12-04  1
1234    Active  A   2017-12-05  1
1234    Active  A   2017-12-06  1
1235    Active  A   2017-12-07  1
1234    Active  A   2018-03-02  1
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-03-03  1
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-03-04  1
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-05-10  1
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-05-11  1
1234    Active  A   2018-05-24  2
1234    Active  A   2018-05-25  2
1234    Active  A   2018-05-26  2
1234    Active  A   2018-05-27  2
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-05-28  2
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-06-15  2
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-06-16  2
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-06-17  2
```

result with my query:

```
    Account Number  Status  Status Code Date    Account_sub_number
1234    Active  A   2017-12-04  1
1234    Active  A   2017-12-05  2
1234    Active  A   2017-12-06  3
1235    Active  A   2017-12-07  4
1234    Active  A   2018-03-02  5
1234    Active  A   2018-05-24  6
1234    Active  A   2018-05-25  7
1234    Active  A   2018-05-26  8
1234    Active  A   2018-05-27  9
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-03-03  1
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-03-04  2
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-05-10  3
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-05-11  4
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-05-28  5
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-06-15  6
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-06-16  7
1234    Cancelled   C   2018-06-17  8
```

Comment: . . Please tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to define groups.  In this case, you can mark where a group begins by looking at an active status following a non-active status.

Then, the cumulative sum of the group starts is the subnumber you are looking for:

```
select a.*,
       sum(case when prev_status_code = status_code or
                     status <> 'Active'
                then 0 else 1
           end) over (partition by account_number order by date range between unbounded preceding and current row) as account_subnumber
from (select a.*,
             lag(status_code) over (partition by account_number order by date) as prev_status_code
      from schema.account a
     ) a
where account_number = 1234
order by date;
```

Comment: I'm getting this error :
ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause

Comment: @Spider . . . As I requested, tag your question with the database you are using.  The window frame clause is optional according to standards.  However, some databases require it.

Answer (score 2):

Get the status on previous row (per account ordered by date) with `lag` and use it for comparison to set groups with a running sum.

```
select t.*
,sum(case when prev_status is null or (prev_status='Cancelled' and status='Active') then 1 else 0 end) 
 over(partition by account_number order by date) as sub_account_number
from (select status,status_code,account_number,date,
      lag(status) over (partition by account_number order by date) as prev_status
      from schema.account 
      where account_number= 1234
     ) a
```